# DataGridView: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

I have a text box through which a `"Name"` column of a `datagridview` is searched but at run time exception throws `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            string searchstring = textBox1.Text;
            try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(searchstring))
                    {
                         Do something   
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It could be one of many reasons as to why that code is throwing a null reference exception. Have you tried debugging it and stepping through each line of code inside the scope of the method? That will indicate which object is null.

Answer (score 0):

Check condition before use `foreach`

**Option 1:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                    {
                           foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                            {
                                if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(searchstring))
                                {
                                     //Do something   
                                }
                            }

                    }

                }

            }
```

**Option 2:**

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                           foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                            {
                                if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(searchstring))
                                {
                                     //Do something   
                                }
                            }

                    }
```

Comment: Same error by 
Changing row.Cells[1] to row.Cells[0]

Comment: What is `DataGridViewRow` type?

Comment: I did not get what do u mean by DataGridViewRow type??

Comment: Updated my answer. Check this out.